# Can MariaDB 'CONNECT' engine with PARTITIONING be used to implement a Column-Oriented database?

Tags: mariadb, parquet

I was looking at the following example from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/using-connect-partitioning-and-sharding/

```
create table partemp (
id int NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(16) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
birth date NOT NULL date_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
hired date NOT NULL date_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
job char(16) NOT NULL,
salary double(10,2) NOT NULL,
city char(12) default 'boston' special=PARTID,
index XID(id)
) engine=CONNECT table_type=FIX file_name='E:/Data/Test/%s.txt';
alter table partemp
partition by list columns(city) (
partition `atlanta` values in('atlanta'),
partition `boston` values in('boston'),
partition `chicago` values in('chicago'));
```

And I'm just wondering, can something like this be extended to multiple columns in order to essentially emulate a PARQUET-like storage format, within a relational database?

Comment: Please explain what you hope to gain by the partitioning.  And, are you having trouble writing?  Or reading?

Comment: I hope to gain the benefits of the PARQUET format, while staying on an RDBMS platform. You can read about PARQUET here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-parquet-columnar-storage-for-apache-hadoop/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but can you point us to less hype and more about  csv and columns.